# C++ initializing template class

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm somewhat baffled as to what is happening when I create my template class. I'm trying to set the capacity of the member vector_ to 50 (only once) during construction, but it seems the capacity is never properly set, so obviously I do not understand how this is supposed to be done. I've included the relevant snippets of code, as well as the console output. Thank you for your help!

Template class for vector:

```
template <typename T>
class V
{
  public:
    V()
    {
      std::cout << "capacity 1 = " << this->vector_.capacity() << "\n";
    };
    V(int capacity)
    {
      this->vector_.reserve(capacity);
      std::cout << "capacity 2 = " << this->vector_.capacity() << "\n";
    };
    int capacity() const { return this->vector_.capacity(); };
  private:
    std::vector<T> vector_;
};
```

Constructor of R where it is initialized:

```
R::R()
{
  std::cout << "capacity 0 = " << this->s_.capacity() << "\n";
  this->s_ = V< std::vector< std::complex<float> > >(50);
  std::cout << "capacity 3 = " << this->s_.capacity() << "\n";
};
```

Header of R class:

```
class R
{
  public:
    R();
  private:
    V< std::vector< std::complex<float> > > s_;
};
```

Output to console:

```
capacity 1 = 0
capacity 0 = 0
capacity 2 = 50
capacity 3 = 0
```

Comment: Missing a _copy-constructor_ perhaps? What is the code that generates that output?

Comment: How does this compile? `s_` is of type `V`, which doesn't have the method `capacity`...

Comment: Also, make V() return something, say a reference to the classes vector, which is problaby why your last line in R's constructor is confusing the crap out of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set the size of the `std::vector<T>` but its capacity. The capacity isn't a salient attribute of `std::vector<T>` and, thus, not copied. You need to use `resize()` to set the size.

Comment: how would I go about setting the capacity correctly since it seems i must use a copy constructor? or is there another way to use a single constructor since i only want to instantiate it once, but in R's constructor...

Comment: @wrapperapps: you will need to provide a copy constructor (and a copy assigment if you assign the objects) which copies the `capacity()`. Note that even when setting a non-zero capacity, the vector's size will stay unchanged, i.e., it is empty but allocates memory

Comment: thank you, i got it to work by adding:


    V& operator=(V const& copy)
    {
      this->vector_ = copy.vector_;
      this->vector_.reserve(copy.vector_.capacity());
      return *this;
    };